# Java is installed but `echo $JAVA_HOME` doesn't seem to produce any output

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I needed Maven for a Java project, so I installed it directly in a fresh Ubuntu installation using `sudo apt install maven`. It automatically downloaded Java 1.8_091 and installed it too. I ran `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the terminal but it doesn't produce any output. How do I rectify this? Is there any problem with environment variables.

Comment: Please set `JAVA_HOME` in the environment variables, so that you will be able to see the output. Otherwise, not. Also see the output of `which java` and set the env. var. accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you download jdk and wants to install in ubuntu, then you need to create an env variable JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file and add this variable to $PATH variable. so that when you echo $JAVA_HOME, you will get the path to your java installation

As u have installed it using sudo apt, it doesn't set JAVA_HOME variable rather installs the java inside /usr/bin folder, and also set alternatives in ubuntu so that ubuntu would be able to identify java

Answer (score 1):

To set JAVA_HOME only in actual shell session, invoke command:

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-<version>
```

To persist this environment variable edit vi **~/.bash_profile** file, and append it to it

Answer (score 1):

To create the variable $JAVA_HOME, you've just to execute these lines :

```
JAVA_HOME=/pathToJavaJDKorJRE/java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Note : If you don't know the path of your JDK or JRE (pathToJavaJDKorJRE), use this command to find them.

```
find / -name 'javac'
```